# how to reformat a number with commas

Tags: php, mysql

I have a line of code that get a count of rows in my table and then display the count. In this case it display the number of downloads.

Right now the count is very small but when it gets larger ( great than 1000) I would like to format it to display with commas in the correct spots example:

1,000

100,000

1,000,000

Or perhaps with a . 1.000 1.000.000

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/number_format) function:

```
$str = number_format($number);
```

To use "." instead of ",":

```
$str = number_format($number, 0, ',', '.');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [FORMAT(X, D)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) in your query:

> Formats the number X to a format like
>   '#,###,###.##', rounded to D decimal
>   places, and returns the result as a
>   string. If D is 0, the result has no
>   decimal point or fractional part.
>
> > mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
> >
> > ```
> >     -> '12,332.1235'
> > ```
> >
> > mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.1,4);
> >
> > ```
> >     -> '12,332.1000'
> > ```
> >
> > mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,0);
> >
> > ```
> >     -> '12,332'
> > ```

Edit:

I was about to add that "*the downside of using this method is that you cannot that number in your code*", but apparently this is not a problem anymore, starting from PHP 5.3, thanks to the [parse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php) function of [NumberFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class:

> **NumberFormatter::parse numfmt_parse**
>
> — Parse a number
>
> Example

```
<?php
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
$num = "1.234.567,891";
echo $fmt->parse($num)."\n";
echo $fmt->parse($num, NumberFormatter::TYPE_INT32)."\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the PHP built-in [`number_format`](http://us.php.net/number_format).

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is looking for the reverse of PHP's [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) function (by the title of this question), here is one:

```
/**
 * @param string $string
 * @param int $decimals
 * @param string $dec_point
 * @param string $thousands_sep
 *
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 * @return float
 */
function number_from_format($string, $decimals = 0, $dec_point = '.', $thousands_sep = ',') {
    $buffer = $string = (string) $string;
    $buffer = strtr($buffer, array($thousands_sep => '', $dec_point => '.'));
    $float = (float) $buffer;
    $test = number_format($float, $decimals, $dec_point, $thousands_sep);
    if ($test !== $string) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to parse float from "%s" as number "%s".', $string, $test));
    }
    return $float;
}
```

Usage Example:

```
var_dump(number_from_format('1,200.00', 2)); # double(1200)
```