# Unformat money when parsing in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, floating-point, currency

Is there a way to get the float value of a string like this: `75,25 €`, other than `parsefloat(str_replace(',', '.', $var))`?

I want this to be dependent on the current site language, and sometimes the comma could be replaced by dot.

Comment: Well there will be localisation issues with regex.

Comment: you can use the solution attached at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407946/parse-formatted-money-string-into-number/19764699#19764699

Comment: Maybe related: [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4325363/608639).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use

- [`NumberFormatter::parseCurrency` - Parse a currency number](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php)

Example from Manual:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
var_dump($formatter->parseCurrency("75,25 €", $curr));
```

gives: `float(75.25)`

Note that the [intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) is not enabled by default. Please refer to the [Installation Instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

Comment: +1 This is a great way of doing it but PHP 5.3 only. This might be a huge constraint

Comment: @Ben PHP5.2 has reached end of support. Also, the intl extension is available in PECL before PHP 5.3, so the version is not an issue.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny what it says in the manual: "Parameter to receive the currency name (3-letter ISO 4217 currency code)." The important word here is receive. It's passed by reference. Think $matches in `preg_match`.

Comment: What is `$curr` in your example?

Comment: @Adam a string denoting a currency; like USD or EUR.

Comment: `NumberFormatter::DECIMAL` if the string is just an amount without currency symbol.

Answer (score 57):

This is a bit more complex/ slow solution, but works with all locales. @rlenom's solution work only with dots as decimal separator, and some locales, like Spanish, use the comma as decimal separator.

```
<?php

public function getAmount($money)
{
    $cleanString = preg_replace('/([^0-9\.,])/i', '', $money);
    $onlyNumbersString = preg_replace('/([^0-9])/i', '', $money);

    $separatorsCountToBeErased = strlen($cleanString) - strlen($onlyNumbersString) - 1;

    $stringWithCommaOrDot = preg_replace('/([,\.])/', '', $cleanString, $separatorsCountToBeErased);
    $removedThousandSeparator = preg_replace('/(\.|,)(?=[0-9]{3,}$)/', '',  $stringWithCommaOrDot);

    return (float) str_replace(',', '.', $removedThousandSeparator);
}
```

Tests:

```
['1,10 USD', 1.10],
['1 000 000.00', 1000000.0],
['$1 000 000.21', 1000000.21],
['£1.10', 1.10],
['$123 456 789', 123456789.0],
['$123,456,789.12', 123456789.12],
['$123 456 789,12', 123456789.12],
['1.10', 1.1],
[',,,,.10', .1],
['1.000', 1000.0],
['1,000', 1000.0]
```

Caveats:
Fails if the decimal part have more than two digits.

This is an implementation from this library:
https://github.com/mcuadros/currency-detector

Comment: Brilliant solution, thank you. The test cases are appreciated

Comment: FYI: merged here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407946/parse-formatted-money-string-into-number

Comment: +1 for this solution, works for me even with French Canadian numbers:
$fr_num = "180,000,08 $";
returns:
double(180000.08)

Comment: Dots inside of character classes do not need to be escaped.

Comment: you people forgot about negative amounts?

Comment: I had to check if string starts with "-" and in that case multiply the result by -1 to change its sign, otherwise this will convert all negative numbers to positive.

Answer (score 47):

use ereg_replace

```
$string = "$100,000";
$int = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $string); 
echo $int;
```

outputs

> 1000000

```
function toInt($str)
{
    return (int)preg_replace("/\..+$/i", "", preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/i", "", $str));
}
```

---

**Update**

---

```
<?php
$string = array("$1,000,000.00","$1 000 000.00","1,000 000.00","$123","$123 456 789","0.15¢");
foreach($string as $s) {
    echo $s . " = " . toInt($s) . "\n"; 
}
function toInt($str)
{
    return preg_replace("/([^0-9\\.])/i", "", $str);
}
?>
```

**Outputs**

```
$1,000,000.00 = 1000000.00
$1 000 000.00 = 1000000.00
1,000 000.00 = 1000000.00
$123 = 123
$123 456 789 = 123456789
0.15¢ = 0.15
```

and if you cast it as an integer

```
<?php
$string = array("$1,000,000.00","$1 000 000.00","1,000 000.00","$123","$123 456 789","0.15¢");
foreach($string as $s) {
    echo $s . " = " . _toInt($s) . "\n";    
}
function _toInt($str)
{
    return (int)preg_replace("/([^0-9\\.])/i", "", $str);
}
?>
```

**outputs**

```
$1,000,000.00 = 1000000
$1 000 000.00 = 1000000
1,000 000.00 = 1000000
$123 = 123
$123 456 789 = 123456789
0.15¢ = 0
```

So there you have it. single line, one replace. you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was hoping I could get away with not using regex, but it's not a performance-critical task, so this is fine. Also, [ereg_replace() is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) - use `preg_replace()` instead :-)

Comment: Might wanna add `.` to the regex to otherwise `$100.00` would equal `10000`.

Comment: sorry, I'm too used to the 5.2 days.

Comment: Mainly as reference, I've got [this function](http://pastebin.com/iQN3MnN1). Is there a way to shrink it into one line?

Comment: @JamWaffles, yup.. there it is.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity; I meant is there a way to get a minor speed increase by shrinking it to one piece of regex, but thank you anyway!

Comment: @JamWaffles, hehe I figured you meant that, I just wanted to give the literal answer. I'll look it over later. Quittin' time!

Comment: shouldn't it be `([^0-9\.])` instead of `([^0-9\\.])` ? Otherwise, the `\\` will not match and it will be left in the final string

Comment: @bruchowski http://tehplayground.com/#YLwjbmpFm looks ok to me. I think you might be technically correct - however this is an old answer and I cannot remember my mindset behind the regex.

Comment: FYI: merged here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407946/parse-formatted-money-string-into-number

Comment: mcuadros's solution work for more locales, but thanks for your input though

Comment: May want to update your answer as the `Function ereg_replace()` has been deprecated.

Comment: I don't think your function handles negatives. I had to change it to `doubleval(preg_replace("/([^0-9\-\\.])/i", "", $stringVal))`. Does mine look okay, or is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: Why does a pattern with no letters in it need a case-insensitive pattern modifier?

Answer (score 10):

You're gonna need to remove the currency symbol from the string.  PHP's `intval` stops at the 1st non-numeric character it finds.

```
$int = intval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', '$100')); // 100
```

Though if you have a value like `$100.25`, you might wanna use `floatval` instead.

```
$float = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', '$100.25')); // 100.25
```

Comment: FYI: merged here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407946/parse-formatted-money-string-into-number

Answer (score 2):

PHP has `intval` ([here are the docs](http://php.net/intval)), which is (as far as I can tell) exactly the same as JavaScript's `parseInt`.

However, for what's worth, I don't think either function will help you with what you're trying to do. Because the first character is non-numeric, both freak out (PHP will give you 0, JS will give you `NaN`). So in either language, you're going to have to do some string/regex parsing.

Comment: FYI: merged here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407946/parse-formatted-money-string-into-number

Answer (score 2):

I'm an newbie, so there's probably an obvious (to others, not me) downside to the approach below, but thought I would share it anyway. I'd be interested to know whether it's faster or slower than using preg_replace, but didn't do any speed testing.

```
$badChars = array("$", ",", "(", ")");
$dirtyString = "($3,895.23)";
$cleanString = str_ireplace($badChars, "", $dirtyString);
echo "$dirtyString becomes $cleanString<p>";
```

$dirtyString can be an array, so:

```
$badChars = array("$", ",", "(", ")");
$dirtyStrings = array("($3,895.23)", "1,067.04", "$5683.22", "$9834.48");
$cleanStrings = str_ireplace($badChars, "", $dirtyStrings);

echo var_dump($cleanStrings);
```

Comment: FYI: merged here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407946/parse-formatted-money-string-into-number

Comment: Like some other suggestions, this is limited to locales that use "." as the decimal and "," as the thousands separator. For those that use comma as the decimal separator, "," is NOT a bad char.

Answer (score 1):

Casting is your friend:

```
$int = (int) $string;
```

---

**Update** <sup>based on op</sup>:

Try something like this:

```
<?php

function extract_numbers($string)
{
    return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $string);
}

echo extract_numbers('$100');

?>
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/QyrfS7WE

Comment: Will that work when the string contains other non-numeric characters like the OP's examples?

Comment: @Rocket -- hmmm i see that now... looking into it

Comment: I experimented with this before I posted my question, but it didn't work - I get the same result as @Rocket.

Comment: Thanks Neal. Your answer is the same as @rlemon's, so both are correct. I'm marking rlemon's answer as correct as he has less rep than you, but I thank you for your efforts nonetheless.

Comment: Might wanna add `.` to the regex to otherwise `$100.00` would equal `10000`.

Comment: @JamWaffles -- that is not really how it works, but ook.... **Especially** since my new update was before that user even posted an answer, but whatever...

Comment: I will accept whichever answer I feel a) is correct and b) deserves the reputation the most. As both your answers are very similar, rlemon gets the tick based on the second criterion.

Comment: oook... thats a very odd and inconsistent way to choose an answer.

Comment: _In my own opinion_, I don't think it is, but I'll just leave it here.

Comment: just as a note to the original answer provided. after posting my new update it would seem casting is **not** my friend. :) _just had to say it_

Comment: FYI: merged here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407946/parse-formatted-money-string-into-number

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I didn't receive the currency symbol, just the strings (ie: 1,234,567.89 or 1.234.567,89).

This helped me normalize both cases into floats:

```
$val = str_replace(",", ".", $formatted);
$val = preg_replace("/[\,\.](\d{3})/", "$1", $val);
```

But Gordon's answer is much cleaner.

Comment: I've left something more specific here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13112263/367456 - however it does not handle any currency symbols around the number itself.

Comment: then just add this to filter out all non-digit and non-separator characters: preg_replace ('/[^\d\,\.]/', '', $val);

Answer (score 0):

filter_var is much faster than regex solutions:

```
   $m = "$1,345.00";
   $m = filter_var($m, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);

   echo $m;
```

1345.00

No sense making it more complicated than it is.