# PHP German Currency Regular Expression

Tags: php, expression, currency

I've been trying all sorts of strange combinations but just can't get my head around Regular Expressions, could somebody help me please. In Germany the , is used instead of a . and a . is used instead of a , e.g. Germen= 10.000,00 English= 10,000.00 I don't need a thousand seperator.

Allowed:

- 1
- 1,0
- 1,00
- ,5
- etc...

Not allowed:

- 1.0
- 1,000
- -,5
- abc
- 0,0€
- etc...

Is it possible to change the format with a Regular Expression so if someone were to enter:
`2` or `2,0` it would be changed to `2,00` and if someone where to enter `,5` it would be changed to `0,50`?

Comment: possible duplicate [PHP Unformat money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money/5140046#5140046)

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 1):

Work with floats in php depends on your locale. You might want to see [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: I'm using the Fabric component for Joomla and it doesn't support it. I can save 0,5 as 0.5 but not as 0.50 and if a user edits the value it is then displayed as 0.5 so I have to save the value as text.