# how to replace(($24.39)) as 24.39 using preg_replace in php?

Tags: php, regex

how to replace(($24.39)) as 24.39 using preg_replace in php?

Comment: Why don't you just use str_replace? The pattern is `(($` and `))`, I see no reason to use regular expressions for that.

Comment: I agree with Michael.  In this case using str_replace would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a large string with multiple occurrences and wanted to replace those in that pattern only...

```
$str = preg_replace('/\(\((\$\d+\.\d+)\)\)/', '$1', $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/IZ2qzZYL).

If you wanted to make the decimal optional, you could change the `\.\d+` to `(?:\.\d+)?`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `preg_replace` or `str_replace` you could also use [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php):

```
echo filter_var(
    '(($24.39))', 
    FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, 
    FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION
); // 24.39
```

[demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/J5r60ksJ)

Related but not applicable as a solution for your given string: [Unformat money when parsing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money)

Answer (score 2):

you could try:

```
$str = "(($24.39))";
$str = preg_replace('/[^\.\d]/',"",$str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: would concur with Michael and Niobita - IF that is the consistent pattern. str_replace is much more efficient...

Answer (score 1):

Regex are expensive. Use:

```
$str = '(($24.39))';
$str = str_replace('(($', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('))', '', $str);
```