# Alternative to money_format() function

Tags: php, money-format

I am trying to use the `money_format()` function in PHP, but it gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function money_format()
```

Searches about this error reveal that the function `money_format()` is only defined if the system has `strfmon` capabilities (for example, Windows does not) and also that the function has been removed from PHP 8.0.

Is there an equivalent PHP function available?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you have the [Intl extension](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php), you can use

- [NumberFormatter::formatCurrency](http://de.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php) — Format a currency value according to the formatter rules.

**Example from Manual**

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'ru_RU', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
```

**Output**

```
1.234.567,89 €
1.234.567,89 RUR
1 234 567,89€
1 234 567,89р.
```

Also see my answer on how to parse that formatted money string back into a float:

- [PHP: unformat money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money/5140046#5140046)

Comment: For US Dollors 
`$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency($float, 'USD');`

Comment: You can see all formats from Wikipedia. https://bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

Answer (score 41):

Keep it simple!

```
sprintf('%01.2f', $val);
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but what if you want the `-` sign in front of the `$` for negative dollar amounts? What if you want `()` instead of `-`?

Comment: @CharityAbbott,
`$val = "-".sprintf('%01.2f;, $val);`
or
`$val = "(".sprintf('%01.2f;, $val).")";`

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php
function toMoney($val,$symbol='$',$r=2)
{


    $n = $val; 
    $c = is_float($n) ? 1 : number_format($n,$r);
    $d = '.';
    $t = ',';
    $sign = ($n < 0) ? '-' : '';
    $i = $n=number_format(abs($n),$r); 
    $j = (($j = $i.length) > 3) ? $j % 3 : 0; 

   return  $symbol.$sign .($j ? substr($i,0, $j) + $t : '').preg_replace('/(\d{3})(?=\d)/',"$1" + $t,substr($i,$j)) ;

}

echo toMoney(9856478521456.256);
?>
```

try this the out put of above code is  "$9,856,478,521,456.26"

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest taking a look into `NumberFormatter` using `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` and locale.

Also Laravel `number_format($price, 2)` function is super useful.

Note, also useful functional that seems to contain similar format:

```
function money_format($floatcurr, $curr = 'EUR')
{
    $currencies['ARS'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Argentine Peso
    $currencies['AMD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Armenian Dram
    $currencies['AWG'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Aruban Guilder
    $currencies['AUD'] = array(2, '.', ' ');          //  Australian Dollar
    $currencies['BSD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bahamian Dollar
    $currencies['BHD'] = array(3, '.', ',');          //  Bahraini Dinar
    $currencies['BDT'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bangladesh, Taka
    $currencies['BZD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Belize Dollar
    $currencies['BMD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bermudian Dollar
    $currencies['BOB'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bolivia, Boliviano
    $currencies['BAM'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bosnia and Herzegovina, Convertible Marks
    $currencies['BWP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Botswana, Pula
    $currencies['BRL'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Brazilian Real
    $currencies['BND'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Brunei Dollar
    $currencies['CAD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Canadian Dollar
    $currencies['KYD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Cayman Islands Dollar
    $currencies['CLP'] = array(0,  '', '.');          //  Chilean Peso
    $currencies['CNY'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  China Yuan Renminbi
    $currencies['COP'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Colombian Peso
    $currencies['CRC'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Costa Rican Colon
    $currencies['HRK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Croatian Kuna
    $currencies['CUC'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Cuban Convertible Peso
    $currencies['CUP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Cuban Peso
    $currencies['CYP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Cyprus Pound
    $currencies['CZK'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Czech Koruna
    $currencies['DKK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Danish Krone
    $currencies['DOP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Dominican Peso
    $currencies['XCD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  East Caribbean Dollar
    $currencies['EGP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Egyptian Pound
    $currencies['SVC'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  El Salvador Colon
    $currencies['ATS'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['BEF'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['DEM'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['EEK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['ESP'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['EUR'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['FIM'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['FRF'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['GRD'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['IEP'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['ITL'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['LUF'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['NLG'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['PTE'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['GHC'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Ghana, Cedi
    $currencies['GIP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Gibraltar Pound
    $currencies['GTQ'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Guatemala, Quetzal
    $currencies['HNL'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Honduras, Lempira
    $currencies['HKD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Hong Kong Dollar
    $currencies['HUF'] = array(0,  '', '.');          //  Hungary, Forint
    $currencies['ISK'] = array(0,  '', '.');          //  Iceland Krona
    $currencies['INR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Indian Rupee
    $currencies['IDR'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Indonesia, Rupiah
    $currencies['IRR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Iranian Rial
    $currencies['JMD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Jamaican Dollar
    $currencies['JPY'] = array(0,  '', ',');          //  Japan, Yen
    $currencies['JOD'] = array(3, '.', ',');          //  Jordanian Dinar
    $currencies['KES'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Kenyan Shilling
    $currencies['KWD'] = array(3, '.', ',');          //  Kuwaiti Dinar
    $currencies['LVL'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Latvian Lats
    $currencies['LBP'] = array(0,  '', ' ');          //  Lebanese Pound
    $currencies['LTL'] = array(2, ',', ' ');          //  Lithuanian Litas
    $currencies['MKD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Macedonia, Denar
    $currencies['MYR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Malaysian Ringgit
    $currencies['MTL'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Maltese Lira
    $currencies['MUR'] = array(0,  '', ',');          //  Mauritius Rupee
    $currencies['MXN'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Mexican Peso
    $currencies['MZM'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Mozambique Metical
    $currencies['NPR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Nepalese Rupee
    $currencies['ANG'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Netherlands Antillian Guilder
    $currencies['ILS'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  New Israeli Shekel
    $currencies['TRY'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  New Turkish Lira
    $currencies['NZD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  New Zealand Dollar
    $currencies['NOK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Norwegian Krone
    $currencies['PKR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Pakistan Rupee
    $currencies['PEN'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Peru, Nuevo Sol
    $currencies['UYU'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Peso Uruguayo
    $currencies['PHP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Philippine Peso
    $currencies['PLN'] = array(2, '.', ' ');          //  Poland, Zloty
    $currencies['GBP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Pound Sterling
    $currencies['OMR'] = array(3, '.', ',');          //  Rial Omani
    $currencies['RON'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Romania, New Leu
    $currencies['ROL'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Romania, Old Leu
    $currencies['RUB'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Russian Ruble
    $currencies['SAR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Saudi Riyal
    $currencies['SGD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Singapore Dollar
    $currencies['SKK'] = array(2, ',', ' ');          //  Slovak Koruna
    $currencies['SIT'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Slovenia, Tolar
    $currencies['ZAR'] = array(2, '.', ' ');          //  South Africa, Rand
    $currencies['KRW'] = array(0,  '', ',');          //  South Korea, Won
    $currencies['SZL'] = array(2, '.', ', ');         //  Swaziland, Lilangeni
    $currencies['SEK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Swedish Krona
    $currencies['CHF'] = array(2, '.', '\'');         //  Swiss Franc
    $currencies['TZS'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Tanzanian Shilling
    $currencies['THB'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Thailand, Baht
    $currencies['TOP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Tonga, Paanga
    $currencies['AED'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  UAE Dirham
    $currencies['UAH'] = array(2, ',', ' ');          //  Ukraine, Hryvnia
    $currencies['USD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  US Dollar
    $currencies['VUV'] = array(0,  '', ',');          //  Vanuatu, Vatu
    $currencies['VEF'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Venezuela Bolivares Fuertes
    $currencies['VEB'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Venezuela, Bolivar
    $currencies['VND'] = array(0,  '', '.');          //  Viet Nam, Dong
    $currencies['ZWD'] = array(2, '.', ' ');          //  Zimbabwe Dollar
    // custom function to generate: ##,##,###.##
    function formatinr($input)
    {
        $dec = "";
        $pos = strpos($input, ".");
        if ($pos === FALSE)
        {
            //no decimals
        }
        else
        {
            //decimals
            $dec   = substr(round(substr($input, $pos), 2), 1);
            $input = substr($input, 0, $pos);
        }
        $num   = substr($input, -3);    // get the last 3 digits
        $input = substr($input, 0, -3); // omit the last 3 digits already stored in $num
        // loop the process - further get digits 2 by 2
        while (strlen($input) > 0)
        {
            $num   = substr($input, -2).",".$num;
            $input = substr($input, 0, -2);
        }
        return $num.$dec;
    }
    if ($curr == "INR")
    {
        return formatinr($floatcurr);
    }
    else
    {
        return number_format($floatcurr, $currencies[$curr][0], $currencies[$curr][1], $currencies[$curr][2]);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to check if the function exist!

```
if (!function_exists('money_format')) { //... }
```

Comment: I'd recommend using this; just drop it into a file, wrap it in the `if (!function_exists("money_format")) { ....` line, and include it before anything that might use it.

Answer (score 7):

I always just used this to manually add the dollar sign:

```
// for $k = 53.234234978
$k = "$ " . number_format($k, 2);
// output = $ 53.23
```

Comment: This doesn't handle negatives in the way most people would want.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem is create a PHP file with the money_format() function and use the Apache auto_prepend_file directive in your php.ini file. Usually, if you use XAMPP, your php.ini should be in

```
C:\XAMPP\php\php.ini
```

Append this line of code to your php.ini file.

```
auto_prepend_file = "C:\money_format.php"
```

use this function in `money_format.php`

```
function money_format($formato, $valor) { 


    if (setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 0) == 'C') { 
        return number_format($valor, 2); 
    }

    $locale = localeconv(); 

    $regex = '/^'.             // Inicio da Expressao 
             '%'.              // Caractere % 
             '(?:'.            // Inicio das Flags opcionais 
             '\=([\w\040])'.   // Flag =f 
             '|'. 
             '([\^])'.         // Flag ^ 
             '|'. 
             '(\+|\()'.        // Flag + ou ( 
             '|'. 
             '(!)'.            // Flag ! 
             '|'. 
             '(-)'.            // Flag - 
             ')*'.             // Fim das flags opcionais 
             '(?:([\d]+)?)'.   // W  Largura de campos 
             '(?:#([\d]+))?'.  // #n Precisao esquerda 
             '(?:\.([\d]+))?'. // .p Precisao direita 
             '([in%])'.        // Caractere de conversao 
             '$/';             // Fim da Expressao 

    if (!preg_match($regex, $formato, $matches)) { 
        trigger_error('Formato invalido: '.$formato, E_USER_WARNING); 
        return $valor; 
    } 

    $opcoes = array( 
        'preenchimento'   => ($matches[1] !== '') ? $matches[1] : ' ', 
        'nao_agrupar'     => ($matches[2] == '^'), 
        'usar_sinal'      => ($matches[3] == '+'), 
        'usar_parenteses' => ($matches[3] == '('), 
        'ignorar_simbolo' => ($matches[4] == '!'), 
        'alinhamento_esq' => ($matches[5] == '-'), 
        'largura_campo'   => ($matches[6] !== '') ? (int)$matches[6] : 0, 
        'precisao_esq'    => ($matches[7] !== '') ? (int)$matches[7] : false, 
        'precisao_dir'    => ($matches[8] !== '') ? (int)$matches[8] : $locale['int_frac_digits'], 
        'conversao'       => $matches[9] 
    ); 

    if ($opcoes['usar_sinal'] && $locale['n_sign_posn'] == 0) { 
        $locale['n_sign_posn'] = 1; 
    } elseif ($opcoes['usar_parenteses']) { 
        $locale['n_sign_posn'] = 0; 
    } 
    if ($opcoes['precisao_dir']) { 
        $locale['frac_digits'] = $opcoes['precisao_dir']; 
    } 
    if ($opcoes['nao_agrupar']) { 
        $locale['mon_thousands_sep'] = ''; 
    } 

    $tipo_sinal = $valor >= 0 ? 'p' : 'n'; 
    if ($opcoes['ignorar_simbolo']) { 
        $simbolo = ''; 
    } else { 
        $simbolo = $opcoes['conversao'] == 'n' ? $locale['currency_symbol'] 
                                               : $locale['int_curr_symbol']; 
    } 
    $numero = number_format(abs($valor), $locale['frac_digits'], $locale['mon_decimal_point'], $locale['mon_thousands_sep']); 


    $sinal = $valor >= 0 ? $locale['positive_sign'] : $locale['negative_sign']; 
    $simbolo_antes = $locale[$tipo_sinal.'_cs_precedes']; 

    $espaco1 = $locale[$tipo_sinal.'_sep_by_space'] == 1 ? ' ' : ''; 

    $espaco2 = $locale[$tipo_sinal.'_sep_by_space'] == 2 ? ' ' : ''; 

    $formatado = ''; 
    switch ($locale[$tipo_sinal.'_sign_posn']) { 
    case 0: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = '('.$simbolo.$espaco1.$numero.')'; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = '('.$numero.$espaco1.$simbolo.')'; 
        } 
        break; 
    case 1: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = $sinal.$espaco2.$simbolo.$espaco1.$numero; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = $sinal.$numero.$espaco1.$simbolo; 
        } 
        break; 
    case 2: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = $simbolo.$espaco1.$numero.$sinal; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = $numero.$espaco1.$simbolo.$espaco2.$sinal; 
        } 
        break; 
    case 3: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = $sinal.$espaco2.$simbolo.$espaco1.$numero; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = $numero.$espaco1.$sinal.$espaco2.$simbolo; 
        } 
        break; 
    case 4: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = $simbolo.$espaco2.$sinal.$espaco1.$numero; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = $numero.$espaco1.$simbolo.$espaco2.$sinal; 
        } 
        break; 
    } 

    if ($opcoes['largura_campo'] > 0 && strlen($formatado) < $opcoes['largura_campo']) { 
        $alinhamento = $opcoes['alinhamento_esq'] ? STR_PAD_RIGHT : STR_PAD_LEFT; 
        $formatado = str_pad($formatado, $opcoes['largura_campo'], $opcoes['preenchimento'], $alinhamento); 
    } 

    return $formatado; 
}
```

Comment: I cant make the auto_prepend to work, but the function does, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of php 8.0 `money_format()`  has been removed. Checkout [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

`money_format()` php function can only be used for php 7.4 and below. Alternatively you can use

`numfmt_format_currency ( NumberFormatter $fmt , float $value , string $currency )` Read more from [here](http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php)

where:

fmt

```
NumberFormatter object.
```

value

```
The numeric currency value.
```

currency

```
The 3-letter ISO 4217 currency code indicating the currency to use.
```

Example:

```
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo numfmt_format_currency($fmt, 1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
```

You can also use a very simple and straight forward laravel package: [money-formatter](https://github.com/Williamug/money-formatter)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why @Ajeet is making it so complicated why not do like this,
It also now works for 4 digit numbers to answer @bharanikumar "but it is not working for the '0899'"

```
function toMoney($val,$symbol='$',$r=2)
{
    $n = $val;
    $sign = ($n < 0) ? '-' : '';
    $i = number_format(abs($n),$r);

    return  $symbol.$sign.$i;
}
```

Comment: Best answer for Windows

Answer (score 2):

```
 function toMoney($val,$symbol='$',$r=2)
{


    $n = $val; 
    $c = is_float($n) ? 1 : number_format($n,$r);
    $d = '.';
    $t = ',';
    $sign = ($n < 0) ? '-' : '';
    $i = $n=number_format(abs($n),$r); 
    $j = (($j = strlen($i)) > 3) ? $j % 3 : 0; 

   return  $symbol.$sign .($j ? substr($i,0, $j) + $t : '').preg_replace('/(\d{3})(?=\d)/',"$1" + $t,substr($i,$j)) ;

}

echo toMoney(45); ;
```

output:$45.00

Comment: Great stuff for those  without both `money_format` and the `NumberFormatter` class. Your solution prints -70927.43 as $-70,927.43 whereas the format -$70,927.43 is more common at least in this neck of the woods. By swapping `$symbol` and `$sign` in the return statement, I achieved what I was interested in.

Comment: Further to my above comment, your code fails for numbers less than 10,000. The value 8994.68 is printed as $8994.68. The fix appears to be $j % 2 (rather than % 3) in the following: `$j = (($j = strlen($i)) > 3) ? $j % 2 : 0;` :) Again, thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `money_format()` you can also try this. Hope this will be helped any guy who faced this `call to undefined function money_format()` error.

```
<?php
    $price = number_format($price, 2); 
    echo "$".$price;
?>
```

Output:

```
$120.00
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ajeet toMoney function looks good, but it is not working for the '0899'

**Change `length` Into `strlen()`**

> $j = (($j = $i.length) > 3) ? $j % 3 : 0;

so change into below like

> $j = (($j = strlen($i)) > 3) ? $j % 3 : 0;

Now this will work for any data.

```
<?php
function toMoney($val,$symbol='$',$r=2)
{


    $n = $val; 
    $c = is_float($n) ? 1 : number_format($n,$r);
    $d = '.';
    $t = ',';
    $sign = ($n < 0) ? '-' : '';
    $i = $n=number_format(abs($n),$r); 
    $j = (($j = strlen($i)) > 3) ? $j % 3 : 0; 

   return  $symbol.$sign .($j ? substr($i,0, $j) + $t : '').preg_replace('/(\d{3})(?=\d)/',"$1" + $t,substr($i,$j)) ;

}

echo toMoney('0899'/100); //Note: single quotes mandatory

?>
```

Comment: I wonder what `$c` and `$d` does. They never used in the function?

Comment: Don't use such obscure variable names. It makes your code into unreadable junk.

Answer (score 0):

@Y Talansky your function could be the next code:

```
function number_to_money($value, $symbol = '$', $decimals = 2)
{
    return $symbol . ($value < 0 ? '-' : '') . number_format(abs($value), $decimals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**

> CLP money (moneda peso chileno, con formato miles)

**

```
    function toMoney($val,$symbol='$',$r=0)
{
    $n = $val; 
    $c = is_float($n) ? 1 : number_format($n,$r);
    $d = '.';
    $t = ',';
    $sign = ($n < 0) ? '-' : '';
    $i = $n=number_format(abs($n),$r); 
    $j = (($j = strlen($i)) > 2) ? $j % 2 : 0; 

   return  $symbol.$sign .($j ? substr($i,0, $j) + $t : '').preg_replace('/(\d{3})(?=\d)/',"$1" + $t,substr($i,$j)) ;

}

echo toMoney(45); $45
echo toMoney(4500);  $4,500
echo toMoney(45000);  $45,000
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
function formatPrice($number, array $options = [])
{
    $options = array_replace([
        'alwaysShowDecimals' => true,
        'nbDecimals' => 2,
        'decPoint' => ".",
        'thousandSep' => "",
        'moneySymbol' => "€",
        'moneyFormat' => "vs", // v represents the value, s represents the money symbol
    ], $options);
    extract($options);

    $v = number_format($number, $nbDecimals, $decPoint, $thousandSep);
    if (false === $alwaysShowDecimals && $nbDecimals > 0) {
        $p = explode($decPoint, $v);
        $dec = array_pop($p);
        if (0 === (int)$dec) {
            $v = implode('', $p);
        }
    }
    $ret = str_replace([
        'v',
        's',
    ], [
        $v,
        $moneySymbol,
    ], $moneyFormat);
    return $ret;

}
```

And use it like this:

```
$numbers = [
    1500,
    90,
    17.52,
    3650.95,
];

$options = [
    'alwaysShowDecimals' => true,
    'nbDecimals' => 2,
    'decPoint' => ".",
    'thousandSep' => "",
    'moneySymbol' => "€",
    'moneyFormat' => "vs", // v represents the value, s represents the money symbol
];
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo formatPrice($number, $options);
    echo "<br>";
}
/**
 * output:
 * 
 * 1500.00€
 * 90.00€
 * 17.52€
 * 3650.95€
 * 
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

This PHP function will give you output based on INR formatting, pass the parameter, and you are done.

```
    function numberToCurrency($number){
        $checkMinusVal = explode('-',$number)[0];
        $checkMinus = $final = '';
        $allStr = explode('.',$number);
        if($checkMinusVal == ''){
            $checkMinus = '-';
            $allStr = explode('.',explode('-',$number)[1]);
        }
        $str = $allStr[0];
        $length = strlen($str);
        $count = $first = 0;
        for($i = $length; $i >= 0; $i--){   
            if($count == 3 && $first == 0){
                $final .= $str[$i];
                if($str[$i + 1] != ''){
                    $final .= ',';
                }
                $count = 0;
                $first = 1;
            }
            elseif($count == 2 && $first == 1){
                if( ($i - 1) < 0){
                    $final .= $str[$i];
                }
                else{
                    $final .= $str[$i].',';
                }
                $count = 0;
            }
            else{
                $final .= $str[$i];
            } 
            $count++;
        }
        $final = strrev($final);
        if(array_key_exists("1",$allStr)){
            $decimalVal = $allStr[1][0];
            if(!empty($allStr[1][1])){
                $decimalVal .= $allStr[1][1];
            }
            else{
                $decimalVal .= 0;
            }
            if($allStr[1][2] >= 5){
                $decimalVal++;
            }
            $final .= '.'.$decimalVal;
        }
        return $checkMinus.'₹'.$final.'/-';
    }
```

In your page call `numberToCurrency($number)` function and it will format and give you output in INR formatting only.

Sample Output:-

`echo numberToCurrency('123')` => `₹123/-`

`echo numberToCurrency('1234')` => `₹1,234/-`

`echo numberToCurrency('1234567')` => `₹12,34,567/-`

`echo numberToCurrency('1234567.123')` => `₹12,34,567.12/-`

`echo numberToCurrency('1234567.125')` => `₹12,34,567.13/-`

`echo numberToCurrency('-1234567.125')` => `-₹12,34,567.13/-`