# Defining cross-platform money_format function (Linux and Windows)

Tags: php, formatting, numbers, number-formatting, money-format

I have read that money_format is not available on windows, and on some Linux distributions (i.e. BSD 4.11 variants). But I want to write cross-platform library using normal function, when available and using this [workaround](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#89060) when not, so my library will be able to run on every PHP-based web server.

Is there any simple solution to check whether built-in function is available and if not to include the solution from above?

Comment: You have ready-for-use code, so what's the question?

Comment: How can I know whether platform supports built-in function? I don't want to use custom one, when normal is available...

Comment: if `function_exists` / `is_callable`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to money\_format() Function in PHP on Windows Platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/alternative-to-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows.

So you can use this php code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, ''); // Locale will be different on each system.
$amount = 1000000.97;
$locale = localeconv();
echo $locale['currency_symbol'], number_format($amount, 2, $locale['decimal_point'], $locale['thousands_sep']);
```

With this you can write code that is actually portable instead of relying on operating system features. Having the money_format function available in PHP without it being an extension is pretty stupid. I don’t see why you would want to create inconsistencies like this between different operating systems in a programming language

Comment: `PHP 5.5.9, Windows 8.1 x64` that function does nothing with the `$amount` regardless of locale.

Comment: And where does it account for negative numbers?

Comment: Didn't considered currency in negative format :) @blackmambo

Answer (score -2):

The `money_format()` is not worked on Windows machine.  So here is your solution for Indian currency format:

```
<?php
    function inr_money_format($number){        
        $decimal = (string)($number - floor($number));
        $money = floor($number);
        $length = strlen($money);
        $delimiter = '';
        $money = strrev($money);

        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
            if(( $i==3 || ($i>3 && ($i-1)%2==0) )&& $i!=$length){
                $delimiter .=',';
            }
            $delimiter .=$money[$i];
        }

        $result = strrev($delimiter);
        $decimal = preg_replace("/0\./i", ".", $decimal);
        $decimal = substr($decimal, 0, 3);

        if( $decimal != '0'){
            $result = $result.$decimal;
        }

        return $result;
    }
?>
```