# How to display Currency in Indian Numbering Format in PHP?

Tags: php, currency, number-formatting, converters, money-format

I have a question about formatting the Rupee currency (Indian Rupee - INR).

For example, numbers here are represented as:

```
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
10,00,000
1,00,00,000
10,00,00,000
```

Refer [Indian Numbering System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

I have to do with it PHP.

I have saw this question [Displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format). But couldn't able to get it for PHP my problem.

## Update:

How to use [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) in indian currency format?

Comment: Maybe here http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php you can find the solution.

Comment: @lgomezma: How to use money_format() in indian currency format?

Comment: The money_format() is deprecated in php 7.4, Please use NumberFormatter

Comment: All the answers below, removes the 0's after the decimal point, if anyone can update the answers to keep the 0's after decimals, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You have so many options but [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) can do the trick for you.

Example:

```
$amount = '100000';
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
$amount = money_format('%!i', $amount);
echo $amount;
```

Output:

```
1,00,000.00
```

Note:

> The function **money_format()** is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so **money_format()** is undefined in Windows.

Pure PHP Implementation - Works on any system:

```
$amount = '10000034000';
$amount = moneyFormatIndia( $amount );
echo $amount;

function moneyFormatIndia($num) {
    $explrestunits = "" ;
    if(strlen($num)>3) {
        $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
        $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); // extracts the last three digits
        $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; // explodes the remaining digits in 2's formats, adds a zero in the beginning to maintain the 2's grouping.
        $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++) {
            // creates each of the 2's group and adds a comma to the end
            if($i==0) {
                $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; // if is first value , convert into integer
            } else {
                $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
            }
        }
        $thecash = $explrestunits.$lastthree;
    } else {
        $thecash = $num;
    }
    return $thecash; // writes the final format where $currency is the currency symbol.
}
```

Comment: If using windows then use [this function for money_format()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974704/cross-platform-money-format-linux-and-windows/10042668#10042668).

Comment: @Somnath Muluk that does not give accurate formatting when using locale with `en_IN`

Comment: Is there any settings to remove zeros after zero if given number is whole number(other than round() function)?

Comment: `substr_replace($string ,"",-1);`  that's the cheat i know ...  @Somnath Muluk

Comment: By doing settings to function money_format() isn't that possible? I don't want to use any hacky method.

Comment: What about a PURE PHP implementation using number_format ... see http://php.net/manual/fr/function.number-format.php

Comment: But with moneyFormatIndia(), if number is '10000034000.45' then it gives '1,00,00,03,40,00,.45' with number format instead of giving '10,00,00,34,000.45'. If number is whole then I don't want numbers after decimal otherwise I want it.

Comment: I have accepted answer, because it helped me to get towards solution.

Comment: Poor function not working with decimals and negative.

Comment: Thanks. After spending over 40 mins trying to figure out why money_format did not work on my Ubuntu 14.04 instance running over nginx on Amazon’s AWS EC2, I settled with this for now. The usual money_format works great on my local homestead machine but couldn’t get the production copy to work. Here’s a [gist](https://gist.github.com/SaifurRahmanMohsin/6f8f37b79ba85db57375) using **money_format** and @Baba's code as a fallback for anyone who faces the same issue.

Comment: this returns wrong output for 5 digit negative value. Ex. for -10000 it returns 0,10,000

Comment: @Baba This is excellent. But one small correction. just before `$thecash = $explrestunits.$lastthree;` we need to add one more line as `$explrestunits = rtrim($explrestunits, ',');` otherwise number shows as `88,43,46,.73`

Comment: Even if on Linux, you might need to generate the `en_IN` locale using the following commands in succession: `sudo locale-gen en_IN.UTF-8` and then `sudo update-locale`

Comment: Second code giving issue for decimal numbers:  https://3v4l.org/vYuPC

Comment: Thank you that works better, but if your number has decimal place and more than 3 after decimal it will give a wrong output, only we have to do is cut the left side of decimal then process and while return decimal result add right side of decimal to it. wonderful thank you very much for the function @Baba

Comment: If you want to display the rupee symbol, you may refer - https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-insert-indian-rupees-symbol-in-php/248733/3

Answer (score 29):

```
$num = 1234567890.123;

$num = preg_replace("/(\d+?)(?=(\d\d)+(\d)(?!\d))(\.\d+)?/i", "$1,", $num);

echo $num;

// Input : 1234567890.123

// Output : 1,23,45,67,890.123


// Input : -1234567890.123

// Output : -1,23,45,67,890.123
```

Comment: I think this should be the fallback method if LC_MONETARY fails.

Comment: I am using Windows and linux hosting, this method works on both like charm, this is the best and shortest method possible for converting any number to INR format.

Comment: This is the best answer, but one problem is that if you have 0 after a decimal value it removes the 0. For example, if the input is. `10000000.40` the output will be `1,00,00,000.4`. If we can make the zero to be there that would be great.

Answer (score 13):

The example you've [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format) is making use of the ICU libraries which are available with PHP in the [intl Extension<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php):

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter($locale = 'en_IN', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $fmt->format(10000000000.1234)."\n"; # Rs 10,00,00,00,000.12
```

Or maybe better fitting in your case:

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter($locale = 'en_IN', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
echo $fmt->format(10000000000)."\n"; # 10,00,00,00,000
```

Comment: That works on windows, the example given has been actually run on windows, see [PHP intl extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1451468/367456).

Comment: How to use `intl Extension­Docs:` library for codeigniter framework? I am unable to use this functions.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: It's just PHP, you use it as-is. If it looks too complicated for you, wrap it into a function of it's own for starters.

Answer (score 13):

```
echo 'Rs. '.IND_money_format(1234567890);

function IND_money_format($money){
    $len = strlen($money);
    $m = '';
    $money = strrev($money);
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
        if(( $i==3 || ($i>3 && ($i-1)%2==0) )&& $i!=$len){
            $m .=',';
        }
        $m .=$money[$i];
    }
    return strrev($m);
}
```

**NOTE:: it is not tested on float values and it suitable for only Integer**

Comment: As **money_format()** doesn't work on Windows. this works for me.

Comment: this returns wrong output for 5 digit negative value. Ex. for -10000 it returns -,10,000.
solution for this is=>  Add if condition like ->

if($money[$i]!="-"){
         $m .=',';
  }

Answer (score 6):

Simply use below function to format in INR.

```
function amount_inr_format($amount) {
    $fmt = new \NumberFormatter($locale = 'en_IN', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
    return $fmt->format($amount);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check this code, it works 100% for Indian Rupees format with decimal format.
You can use numbers like :

123456.789
 123.456
 123.4
 123
 and 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.222

```
function moneyFormatIndia($num){

$explrestunits = "" ;
$num = preg_replace('/,+/', '', $num);
$words = explode(".", $num);
$des = "00";
if(count($words)<=2){
    $num=$words[0];
    if(count($words)>=2){$des=$words[1];}
    if(strlen($des)<2){$des="$des";}else{$des=substr($des,0,2);}
}
if(strlen($num)>3){
    $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
    $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); // extracts the last three digits
    $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; // explodes the remaining digits in 2's formats, adds a zero in the beginning to maintain the 2's grouping.
    $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++){
        // creates each of the 2's group and adds a comma to the end
        if($i==0)
        {
            $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; // if is first value , convert into integer
        }else{
            $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
        }
    }
    $thecash = $explrestunits.$lastthree;
} else {
    $thecash = $num;
}
return "$thecash.$des"; // writes the final format where $currency is the currency symbol.

}
```

Answer (score 3):

When money_format is not available :

```
function format($amount): string
{
    list ($number, $decimal) = explode('.', sprintf('%.2f', floatval($amount)));

    $sign = $number < 0 ? '-' : '';

    $number = abs($number);

    for ($i = 3; $i < strlen($number); $i += 3)
    {
        $number = substr_replace($number, ',', -$i, 0);
    }

    return $sign . $number . '.' . $decimal;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$amount = '-100000.22222';    // output -1,00,000.22 
//$amount = '0100000.22222';  // output 1,00,000.22 
//$amount = '100000.22222';   // output 1,00,000.22 
//$amount = '100000.';       // output 1,00,000.00 
//$amount = '100000.2';     // output 1,00,000.20
//$amount = '100000.0';    // output 1,00,000.00 
//$amount = '100000';      // output 1,00,000.00 

echo $aaa = moneyFormatIndia($amount);

function moneyFormatIndia($amount)
    {

        $amount = round($amount,2);

        $amountArray =  explode('.', $amount);
        if(count($amountArray)==1)
        {
            $int = $amountArray[0];
            $des=00;
        }
        else {
            $int = $amountArray[0];
            $des=$amountArray[1];
        }
        if(strlen($des)==1)
        {
            $des=$des."0";
        }
        if($int>=0)
        {
            $int = numFormatIndia( $int );
            $themoney = $int.".".$des;
        }

        else
        {
            $int=abs($int);
            $int = numFormatIndia( $int );
            $themoney= "-".$int.".".$des;
        }   
        return $themoney;
    }

function numFormatIndia($num)
    {

        $explrestunits = "";
        if(strlen($num)>3)
        {
            $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
            $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); // extracts the last three digits
            $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; // explodes the remaining digits in 2's formats, adds a zero in the beginning to maintain the 2's grouping.
            $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
            for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++) {
                // creates each of the 2's group and adds a comma to the end
                if($i==0) {
                    $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; // if is first value , convert into integer
                } else {
                    $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
                }
            }
            $thecash = $explrestunits.$lastthree;
        } else {
            $thecash = $num;
        }
        return $thecash; // writes the final format where $currency is the currency symbol.
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this a quick and simplest solution:-

```
        function formatToInr($number){
        $number=round($number,2);
        // windows is not supported money_format
    if(setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN')){
         return money_format('%!'.$decimal.'n', $number);
         }
     else {
        if(floor($number) == $number) {
            $append='.00';
        }else{
            $append='';
        }
        $number = preg_replace("/(\d+?)(?=(\d\d)+(\d)(?!\d))(\.\d+)?/i", "$1,", $number);
        return $number.$append;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm reading that right, the Indian Numbering System separates the thousands, then every power of a hundred past that? Hmm...

Perhaps something like this?

```
function indian_number_format($num) {
    $num = "".$num;
    if( strlen($num) < 4) return $num;
    $tail = substr($num,-3);
    $head = substr($num,0,-3);
    $head = preg_replace("/\B(?=(?:\d{2})+(?!\d))/",",",$head);
    return $head.",".$tail;
}
```

Comment: You need to do something about numbers that contain decimals.

Answer (score 1):

I have used different format parameters to money_format() for my output.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
if (ctype_digit($amount) ) {
     // is whole number
     // if not required any numbers after decimal use this format 
     $amount = money_format('%!.0n', $amount);
}
else {
     // is not whole number
     $amount = money_format('%!i', $amount);
}
//$amount=10043445.7887 outputs 1,00,43,445.79
//$amount=10043445 outputs 1,00,43,445
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$amount=-3000000000111.11;
$amount<0?(($sign='-').($amount*=-1)):$sign=''; //Extracting sign from given amount
$pos=strpos($amount, '.'); //Identifying the decimal point position
$amt=  substr($amount, $pos-3); // Extracting last 3 digits of integer part along with fractional part
$amount=  substr($amount,0, $pos-3); //removing the extracted part from amount
for(;strlen($amount);$amount=substr($amount,0,-2)) // Now loop through each 2 digits of remaining integer part
    $amt=substr ($amount,-2).','.$amt; //forming Indian Currency format by appending (,) for each 2 digits
echo $sign.$amt; //Appending sign
```

Comment: Please give explanation to your answer. Code only answers are not appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the number_format function.[Here is the link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Separating thousands with commas will look like

```
$rupias = number_format($number, 2, ',', ',');
```

Comment: I have checked that. How to use money_format() in indian currency format?

Answer (score 0):

Above Function Not working with Decimal

```
$amount = 10000034000.001;
$amount = moneyFormatIndia( $amount );
echo $amount;




function moneyFormatIndia($num){
        $nums = explode(".",$num);
        if(count($nums)>2){
            return "0";
        }else{
        if(count($nums)==1){
            $nums[1]="00";
        }
        $num = $nums[0];
        $explrestunits = "" ;
        if(strlen($num)>3){
            $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
            $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); 
            $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; 
            $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
            for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++){

                if($i==0)
                {
                    $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; 
                }else{
                    $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
                }
            }
            $thecash = $explrestunits.$lastthree;
        } else {
            $thecash = $num;
        }
        return $thecash.".".$nums[1]; 
        }
    }
```

Answer : 10,00,00,34,000.001

Answer (score 0):

It's my very own function to do the task

```
function bd_money($num) {
    $pre = NULL; $sep = array(); $app = '00';
    $s=substr($num,0,1);
    if ($s=='-') {$pre= '-';$num = substr($num,1);}
    $num=explode('.',$num);
    if (count($num)>1) $app=$num[1];
    if (strlen($num[0])<4) return $pre . $num[0] . '.' . $app;
    $th=substr($num[0],-3);
    $hu=substr($num[0],0,-3);
    while(strlen($hu)>0){$sep[]=substr($hu,-2); $hu=substr($hu,0,-2);}
    return $pre.implode(',',array_reverse($sep)).','.$th.'.'.$app;
}
```

It took 0.0110 Seconds per THOUSAND query while number_format took 0.001 only.
Always try to use PHP native functions only when performance is target issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
function addCommaToRs($amt, &$ret, $dec='', $sign=''){
    if(preg_match("/-/",$amt)){
        $amts=explode('-',$amt);
        $amt=$amts['1'];
        static $sign='-';
    } 
    if(preg_match("/\./",$amt)){
        $amts=explode('.',$amt);
        $amt=$amts['0'];
        $l=strlen($amt);
        static $dec;
        $dec=$amts['1'];
    } else {
        $l=strlen($amt);
    }
    if($l>3){
        if($l%2==0){
            $ret.= substr($amt,0,1);
            $ret.= ",";
            addCommaToRs(substr($amt,1,$l),$ret,$dec);
        } else{
            $ret.=substr($amt,0,2);
            $ret.= ",";     
            addCommaToRs(substr($amt,2,$l),$ret,$dec);
        }
    } else {
        $ret.= $amt;
        if($dec) $ret.=".".$dec;
    }
    return $sign.$ret; 
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$amt = '';
echo addCommaToRs(123456789.123,&$amt,0);
```

This will return `12,34,567.123`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$r=explode('.',12345601.20);

$n = $r[0];
$len = strlen($n); //lenght of the no
$num = substr($n,$len-3,3); //get the last 3 digits
$n = $n/1000; //omit the last 3 digits already stored in $num
while($n > 0) //loop the process - further get digits 2 by 2
{
    $len = strlen($n);
    $num = substr($n,$len-2,2).",".$num;
    $n = round($n/100);
}
echo "Rs.".$num.'.'.$r[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use any inbuilt function in my case i was doing on iis server so was unable to use one the function in php so did this

```
$num = -21324322.23;


moneyFormatIndiaPHP($num);
function moneyFormatIndiaPHP($num){
    //converting it to string 
    $numToString = (string)$num;

    //take care of decimal values
    $change = explode('.', $numToString);

    //taking care of minus sign
    $checkifminus =  explode('-', $change[0]);


    //if minus then change the value as per
    $change[0] = (count($checkifminus) > 1)? $checkifminus[1] : $checkifminus[0];

    //store the minus sign for further
    $min_sgn = '';
    $min_sgn = (count($checkifminus) > 1)?'-':'';



    //catch the last three
    $lastThree = substr($change[0], strlen($change[0])-3);



    //catch the other three
    $ExlastThree = substr($change[0], 0 ,strlen($change[0])-3);


    //check whethr empty 
    if($ExlastThree != '')
        $lastThree = ',' . $lastThree;


    //replace through regex
    $res = preg_replace("/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/",",",$ExlastThree);

    //main container num
    $lst = '';

    if(isset($change[1]) == ''){
        $lst =  $min_sgn.$res.$lastThree;
    }else{
        $lst =  $min_sgn.$res.$lastThree.".".$change[1];
    }

    //special case if equals to 2 then 
    if(strlen($change[0]) === 2){
        $lst = str_replace(",","",$lst);
    }

    return $lst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This for both integer and float values**

```
    function indian_money_format($number)
    {

        if(strstr($number,"-"))
        {
            $number = str_replace("-","",$number);
            $negative = "-";
        }

        $split_number = @explode(".",$number);

        $rupee = $split_number[0];
        $paise = @$split_number[1];

        if(@strlen($rupee)>3)
        {
            $hundreds = substr($rupee,strlen($rupee)-3);
            $thousands_in_reverse = strrev(substr($rupee,0,strlen($rupee)-3));
            $thousands = '';
            for($i=0; $i<(strlen($thousands_in_reverse)); $i=$i+2)
            {
                $thousands .= $thousands_in_reverse[$i].$thousands_in_reverse[$i+1].",";
            }
            $thousands = strrev(trim($thousands,","));
            $formatted_rupee = $thousands.",".$hundreds;

        }
        else
        {
            $formatted_rupee = $rupee;
        }

        if((int)$paise>0)
        {
            $formatted_paise = ".".substr($paise,0,2);
        }else{
            $formatted_paise = '.00';
        }

        return $negative.$formatted_rupee.$formatted_paise;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function moneyFormatIndia($num) 
    {
        //$num=123456789.00;
        $result='';
        $sum=explode('.',$num);
        $after_dec=$sum[1];
        $before_dec=$sum[0];
        $result='.'.$after_dec;
        $num=$before_dec;
        $len=strlen($num);
        if($len<=3) 
        {
            $result=$num.$result;
        }
        else
        {
            if($len<=5)
            {
                $result='Rs '.substr($num, 0,$len-3).','.substr($num,$len-3).$result;
                return $result;
            }
            else
            {
                $ls=strlen($num);
                $result=substr($num, $ls-5,2).','.substr($num, $ls-3).$result;
                $num=substr($num, 0,$ls-5);
                while(strlen($num)!=0)
                {
                    $result=','.$result;
                    $ls=strlen($num);
                    if($ls<=2)
                    {
                        $result='Rs. '.$num.$result;
                        return $result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $result=substr($num, $ls-2).$result;
                        $num=substr($num, 0,$ls-2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of this money format issue.

```
$amount = 1000.45;
function indian_money_format($amount){
    $e = explode('.',$amount);
    $left = $e[0];
    $right = $e[1];
    $nLeft = [];
    $rev_left= strrev($left);
    $left_count = strlen($rev_left);
    for($x=0;$x<$left_count;$x++){
        $nLeft[] = $rev_left[$x];
        if ($x==2){
            $nLeft[] = ',';
        }else if (($x+1)%2 == 1 && $x>=3){
            $nLeft[] = ',';
        }
    }
    $amount = ltrim(strrev(implode('',$nLeft)),',').".".$right;
    return $amount;
}


echo "<hr>";
echo indian_money_format($amount);
```

Answer (score -3):

heres is simple thing u can do ,

```
 float amount = 100000;

 NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));

 String moneyString = formatter.format(amount);

 System.out.println(moneyString);
```

The output will be , Rs.100,000.00 .

Comment: Isn't question is for PHP?

Answer (score -3):

```
declare @Price decimal(26,7)
Set @Price=1234456677
select FORMAT(@Price,  'c', 'en-In')
```

**Result:**

```
1,23,44,56,677.00
```