# Formatting currency based on Indian numbering system in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I used PHP's **NumberFormatter**. But I am getting the error as '*NumberFormatter not found*'. Then I used the **Money package**, https://packagist.org/packages/money/money but, there is no support for the INR(Indian Currency).

Though I am not much concerned with the *rupee* symbol with the number, at least I need to format the number; **for eg:** from **7827894.8** to **78,27,894.80**. 
How can I achieve it?

I am not able to use,

- NumberFormatter (Intl package is not detecting though I uncommented it from php.ini)
- money_format()  (as mine is windows system)
- Money/Money Package (no function available for my problem)

Please help me to achive a correct way of representing the money(either by using any *package* or by using a *custom function*) **TIA**.

Comment: `number_format ( 7827894.8  , 2 , "." , "," )` checkthe manual page http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: @JulioSoares if they format numbers as in the OP's example (groups of **2** digits after the first 3), then `number_format` isn't going to do it.

Comment: @Kryten you are absolutely right. Sorry for my lack of attention. I've never heard of a numbering system like this before.

Answer (score 1):

**From one of my [github gists](https://gist.github.com/SapneshNaik/94250492b8eaaf874773165782c9a3f5) I wrote a  few months ago,**

```
<?php
    function IND_money_format($money){

            $decimal = (string)($money - floor($money));
            $money = floor($money);
            $length = strlen($money);
            $m = '';
            $money = strrev($money);
            for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
                if(( $i==3 || ($i>3 && ($i-1)%2==0) )&& $i!=$length){
                    $m .=',';
                }
                $m .=$money[$i];
            }
            $result = strrev($m);
            $decimal = preg_replace("/0\./i", ".", $decimal);
            $decimal = substr($decimal, 0, 3);
            if( $decimal != '0'){
            $result = $result.$decimal;
            }
            return $result;
        }
?>
```

**How to add this as a global helper function in laravel?**

1 - Create a `Helpers` directory for your helper functions in the app directory 
    `mkdir app/Helpers' .

2 - Download the `Indian_currency_format.php` file and save it to Helpers directory.

3 - In your composer.json add the file to "files" attribute of autoload so that it can be loaded by composer using PSR-4 autoloading 
    (see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4),

```
like so:
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "database/seeds",
                "database/factories"
             ],
             "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/"
             },
             "files": [
                "app/Helpers/indian_money_format.php"
             ]
        },
```

4 - Finally run `composer dump-autoload` to refresh autoload cache.

Check out my blog post on [how to format a number to Indian Rupee format in PHP / Laravel](https://www.kerneldev.com/2017/11/30/how-to-format-a-number-to-indian-currency-format-in-php-laravel/) to learn in depth how this function actually works.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use any packages for this and yet want to do this in a laravel way, i suggest you do the following. the solution has a blend of pure PHP. i have tested this in laravel 5 and it works well.

first create HelperServiceProvider by running:

> php artisan make:provider HelperServiceProvider

then open config/app.php and register the service provider:

```
'providers' => [

    /* other providers */

    'App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider',

]
```

now create a folder **app\Helpers** and in that folder create a file **moneyformat.php**

```
<?php

/* moneyformat.php */

    function rupee_format($num) {
        $explrestunits = "" ;
        if(strlen($num)>3){
            $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
            $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); // extracts the last three digits
            $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; // explodes the remaining digits in 2's formats, adds a zero in the beginning to maintain the 2's grouping.
            $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
            for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++){
                // creates each of the 2's group and adds a comma to the end
                if($i==0)
                {
                    $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; // if is first value , convert into integer
                }else{
                    $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
                }
            }
            $thecash = $explrestunits.$lastthree;
        } else {
            $thecash = $num;
        }
        return $thecash; // writes the final format where $currency is the currency symbol.
    }
```

now you'll be able to display the numbers in your blade files like this :

```
{{ rupee_format($price) }}
```

references [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042485/how-to-display-currency-in-indian-numbering-format-in-php)