# How to show number in readable format

Tags: php

I want to know how can I add comma's to numbers. I want to change number `5,272,945.31` to `52,72,945.31` 
Is it possible with a php function?

I have try this code:

```
number_format($amount,2);
```

Comment: see [Numbering Format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042485/how-to-display-currency-in-indian-numbering-format-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The value assigned to `$amount` isn't formatted correctly, however, `number_format` doesn't like `,` so strip these out before passing to `number_format`.

```
number_format(str_replace(',', '', $amount), 2);
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/dPAEp