# Is there any way to format or convert number in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When I use the PHP function format_number to convert my variable value which is like `123456789`, it converts it with thousand separators like this: `123,456,789`. What I want is to format it like this: `12,34,56,789`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the logic in this formatting?

Comment: Actual client requirement, it will be easy to read out. any suggestion please.

Comment: In logic I mean what is the algorithm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display Currency in Indian Numbering Format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042485/how-to-display-currency-in-indian-numbering-format-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10042593/1333899):

```
$amount = 123456789;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
$amount = money_format('%!.0i', $amount);
```

You can then pass the `$amount` variable to your blade template.