# preserving 0's after decimal point while displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format in PHP

Tags: php, currency, number-formatting

I need to display '150000.50' in Indian number format with the last zero intact.

I followed the following, but the solution
[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042485/how-to-display-currency-in-indian-numbering-format-in-php/54603979#54603979) doesn't completely solve the issue. It removes the last 0 from the number which is required in my case.

1.

```
preg_replace("/(\d+?)(?=(\d\d)+(\d)(?!\d))(\.\d+)?/i", "$1,", $num);
 // Output: 1,50,000.5 
// Expected output: 1,50,500.50
```

2. 

```
new NumberFormatter($locale = 'en_IN', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL); from Intl extension.
// Output: 1,50,000.5
// Expected output: 1,50,500.50
```

`money_format` is now deprecated. If anyone can update `preg_replace` function regex to preserve the trailing zero, it will be helpful.

Comment: If you're asking about the same issue, then it's still a duplicate of that question - it is open for more answers to be added if people create them. We don't need the effort to be split between this question and that one.

Comment: There appear to be examples using both `preg_replace` and `NumberFormatter` in the answers to the question you linked. Why are you asking again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display Currency in Indian Numbering Format in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042485/how-to-display-currency-in-indian-numbering-format-in-php)

Comment: Expected output is 1,50,000.50 
Output given by all the suggested answers were 1,50,000.5
I added comment in the suggested answer for this, solutions. that's why I asked this as a new question.