# PHP number_format() Function

Tags: php

I am trying to format my number in the following way

```
12,34,56,789.00
```

i tried

`number_format($row{'money'},2,".",",")`

I am getting

```
123,456,789.00
```

This is not what i wanted. So, How to do this?? (`12,34,56,789.00`)

Comment: The `number_format()` method formats a number within defined/standard groups (i.e. thousands, millions, etc). Your requested format, 2 numbers + comma + 2 numbers + comma, is not a standard format. You'll have to write your own function to do that grouping (possibly with `money_format()`).

Comment: You can’t do that with number_format, because the functions purpose is explicitly _“format a number with grouped thousands”_.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this just by using the PHP function called [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

```
$amount = '123456789.00';
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
$amount = money_format('%!i', $amount);
echo $amount; // 12,34,56,789.00
```

The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows.

So you can use this php code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, ''); // Locale will be different on each system.
$amount = 123456789.00;
$locale = localeconv();
echo number_format($amount, 2, $locale['decimal_point'], $locale['thousands_sep']);
```

Comment: Is it working ? , if you keep $amount as 123456789 ( without .00 )

Comment: Really sorry, Please refer the following questions.. So, you can get the idea..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/how-we-can-use-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974704/cross-platform-money-format-linux-and-windows