# Getting fatal error in money_format function

Tags: php

Why does this error occurs?

code:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
$pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
```

Server details.

```
Apache Version : 2.2.21  
PHP Version : 5.3.8
```

I'm getting the following Error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function money_format()
```

Comment: do you have any other code? that should work; only reason I could suggest at this junction is that you're inside a namespace...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How we can use money_format() function in php on windows platform.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/how-we-can-use-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform)

Comment: Here is the Solutions.. It Worked .http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#89060

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php):

> The function `money_format()` is only defined if the system has `strfmon`
>   capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so `money_format()` is
>   undefined in Windows.

`money_format()` is basically a wrapper around the C library function `strfmon()` as the manual states.

If you check the comments, there is [an implementation by Rafael M. Salvioni](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#89060). Worth a try. You can check if it's already defined using [function_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php).

Answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/alternative-to-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform) give further (and possibly better) alternatives ([thx danielson317](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715658/getting-fatal-error-in-money-format-function/10715728?noredirect=1#comment48020238_10715728)).

Comment: I just add function there is an implementation by Rafael M. Salvioni to my web then it's works. +1 for the links

Comment: That function doesn't work for me. I get Severity: Warning

Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: the intl module mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/how-we-can-use-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform is a much better solution.
Still +1 for being a valid answer.

Comment: @danielson317 Thanks, added the link to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For those that money_format doesn't work, you can use:

```
$price = number_format($price, 2); echo “$”.$price;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

> Note:
>
> The function `money_format()` is only defined if the system has `strfmon` capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so `money_format()` is undefined in Windows.
>
> http://php.net/money_format

Comment: there is any solutions for window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/how-we-can-use-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform