# Convert ToMoney function not working

Tags: php, currency

Function not working for prefix with 8[any numbers].

input: 970 output:$9.70
input: 870 output:$870
input: 800 output:$800

```
function toMoney( $val, $symbol = '$', $r = 2 ) {
    $n = $val; 
    $c = is_float($n) ? 1 : number_format( $n , $r );
    $d = '.';
    $t = ',';
    $sign = ( $n < 0 ) ? '-' : '';
    $i = $n = number_format( abs( $n ), $r ); 
    $j = ( ( $j = $i.length ) > 3 ) ? $j % 3 : 0; 

   return  $symbol.$sign .( $j ? substr( $i, 0, $j) + $t : '').preg_replace('/(\d{3})(?=\d)/',"$1" + $t,substr($i,$j)) ;
}
```

Function taken from: [Money conversion not worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/how-we-can-use-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform)

The above error rectified in the below

```
  function toMoney( $val, $symbol = '$', $r = 2 ) {
        $n = $val; 
        $c = is_float($n) ? 1 : number_format( $n , $r );
        $d = '.';
        $t = ',';
        $sign = ( $n < 0 ) ? '-' : '';
        $i = $n = number_format( abs( $n ), $r ); 
        $j = ( ( $j = strlen($i) ) > 3 ) ? $j % 3 : 0; 

       return  $symbol.$sign .( $j ? substr( $i, 0, $j) + $t : '').preg_replace('/(\d{3})(?=\d)/',"$1" + $t,substr($i,$j)) ;
    }
```

Comment: Tried it and got $670.00 for 670 and $800.00 for 800

Comment: but i am getting just $800

Comment: `$i.length` ? what kind of notation is that in PHP? Also, you are using `+` as string concat operator while you should use `.`, see for example your last line.

Comment: @Sankalp Mishra please double check ur input and output, please tell me your PHP Version.

Comment: some one please suggest fix for the above function

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari converted length into strlen($var) and problem fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you want the two last numbers to be cents?

so why don't just do :

```
$val = number_format(intval(substr($val,0,strlen($val)-2)),).'.'.substr($val,-2);
```

the first `substr` will just forget the two last digits and then will be formated with only thousand separator. 
the second `substr` just take the two last numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo '$' . money_format('%i', $number/100) . "\n";
```

Comment: Maybe you should also put a few words here, don't just post a code.

Comment: +1 for using native PHP functions, without reinventing the wheel