# how to format a column as currency in GridView(yii)?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Hello everyone and thanks for reading . 
I was wondering how i could format a number into a currency or just simply attach € at the end. I am working in a gridview on the admin page in the yii framework. 
i have this as eg

```
'columns'=>array(
        'title',
            array(
                'name'=>'cost',
                'value'=>'$data->cost',
            )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Yii way would be to use [Yii's existing currency formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CNumberFormatter/#formatCurrency-detail), like this:

```
array(
      'name'=>'cost',
      'value'=>'Yii::app()->numberFormatter->formatCurrency($data->cost, "EUR")',
     )
```

Comment: yhea this is what i was looking for , this is the yii way

Comment: In Yii2 we have: Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency()

Answer (score 2):

You can use php functions and some static text in value. Example:

```
'columns'=>array(
        'title',
            array(
                'name'=>'cost',
                'value'=>'$data->cost . " €" ',
            )
```

If you need to use this kind of formatting even more, I suggest to write a custom function to controller or extend CFormatter with custom currency function and use it as value. Please ead the yii homepage manual below.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/278/cgridview-render-customized-complex-datacolumns/

Answer (score 1):

I use php's [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) to get the correct formatting.

It could look like this:

```
'columns'=>array(
    'title',
        array(
            'name'=>'cost',
            'value'=>'money_format("%!i", $data->cost)',
        )
```

You can specify a currency by setting locale **before** calling money_format(), like this:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'ja_JP');
```

ja_JP is for japanese yen, used just as an example. [More here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/list-of-all-locales-and-their-short-codes)

Comment: I call it in my SiteController. public function init(){ setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'ja_JP'); }  but you can call it pretty much anywhere as long as it's executed before money_format(). Personally, I think this *should* be set by YII when you set another language in your config.

Comment: This solution works on the server, but if you use Windows on the localhost , than you receive "Fatal error: Call to undefined function money_format()". See e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/alternative-to-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform