# PHP Money Fomat

Tags: php, money-format

I have a full `int` value already with the decimals and I want to convert like this in PHP

```
500 -> 5,00$
 5070 -> 50,70$
 50070 -> 500,70$
 500000 -> 5.000,00$
```

so the format should be like this `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xx$`

any function for that?

Comment: money_format
        number_format

Comment: Did you do any research at all before asking? Considering that there is a php function called `money_format`, just searching for your title would have given you at least that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is there a local that use dot `.` as thousand separator and `,` as decimal separator for `money_format` ?

Comment: @Cid - I have no idea. But the fact that the OP didn't even mention that function or showed any attempt at all, it leads me to believe that they haven't checked. They would probably also have found the `number_format()`-function quite quickly as well.

Comment: looks like he did researches, but he forgot to mention it and to show us the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) can do the job.

It works like this : `string number_format(float $number, int $decimals = 0, string $dec_point = ".", string $thousands_sep = ",")`

> number
>
> The number being formatted.
>
> decimals
>
> Sets the number of decimal points.
>
> dec_point
>
> Sets the separator for the decimal point.
>
> thousands_sep
>
> Sets the thousands separator.

In your case, that could be `$myMoney = number_format($cents / 100, 2, ",", ".") . "$";`

Comment: I tryed this function a couple times but seams doesn't do want I want. If I have 5006 this outputs 5.006$ and sould be 50,60$.
with `number_format($number, 0, ",",".") . "$";`

Comment: Of course this won't, read again the code I provided. You first have to convert cents to dollar (hint, a dollar is 100 cents, hence `$cents / 100`). The second argument is the number of digit on the right side of the decimal point.

Comment: By the way, you **should** have provided that piece of code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have your money format in cents so you can do:

```
$prices = [
    500,
    5070,
    50070,
    500000
];
foreach ($prices as $price) {
    echo money_format("Price: %i", $price / 100);
}
```

Comment: I need a alternative to money_format() this function doesn't work on windows servers.

Comment: @RodrigoBorba - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/alternative-to-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform - It took about 5 seconds to find. Please always start by doing proper research...