# What a quick way to clean up a monetary string

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: unformat money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money)

How to get rid of everything that is not a number or dot, replacing `,` with `.` using a light regex?

Examples:

```
$50.45     = 50.45
USD 50.45  = 50.45
50,45      = 50.45
USD$ 50.45 = 50.45
```

Comment: what about pointless data like '50 foo bar 45'?

Comment: @wonk0 i think this would get the first 50

Comment: so the string *can* start with "USD" and/or "$" followed by digits; optionally followed by "," or ".", followed by more digits?

Comment: @Gordon i'm not looking to translate the currency, The service only takes USD.

Comment: What should be produced for `USD 3,050.39`?

Comment: This answer worked like a charm: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19764699/327862

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$money = array(
    '$50.45',
    'USD 50.45',
    '50,45',
    'USD$ 50.45'
);

// remove everything except a digit "0-9", a comma ",", and a dot "."
$money = preg_replace('/[^\d,\.]/', '', $money);

// replace the comma with a dot, in the number format ",12" or ",43"
$money = preg_replace('/,(\d{2})$/', '.$1', $money);

print_r($money);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 50.45
    [1] => 50.45
    [2] => 50.45
    [3] => 50.45
)
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work for $1,799.00 gives 1.799.00

Comment: @malhal fixed. Should work fine now. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/.*?(\d+)(?:[.,](\d+))?.*/', '\1.\2', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks, but `USD 54` returns `1.2`

Comment: @David You must be using a special version of PHP. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/YpFKRk

Comment: This puts a decimal point following the number, even if there is nothing following it... perhaps `rtrim(preg_replace('/.*?(\d+)(?:[.,](\d+))?.*/', '\1.\2', $string), '. ');`?

Comment: @Brendan If that's a problem, you can also convert it to a float and back with `(string)(float) preg...`.

Comment: Hi @Artefacto - if you have the time, could u explain your regex ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with that works with your examples was:

```
preg_replace("([^0-9\.])","",str_replace(",",".",$val));
```

Assuming comma only ever appears when it should be a decimal point, as opposed to being a thousands separator.  It replaces those with a decimal place, and then removes all non numeric/decimal characters from the remaining string altogether.

Test script:

```
$inputs = array("\$50.45", "USD 50.45", "50,45", "USD\$ 50.45");

foreach ($inputs as $val) {
    $cleanVal = preg_replace("([^0-9\.])","",str_replace(",",".",$val));
    echo "GIVEN: <b>".$val."</b> -> CLEAN: <b>".$cleanVal."</b><br/>";    
}
```

Output:

> GIVEN: $50.45 -> CLEAN: 50.45
>
> GIVEN: USD 50.45 -> CLEAN: 50.45
>
> GIVEN: 50,45 -> CLEAN: 50.45
>
> GIVEN: USD$ 50.45 -> CLEAN: 50.45

Comment: Doesn't work, try $5,000.45 it gives 5.000.45

Answer (score 0):

This would work too for the given examples ([demo](http://codepad.org/ZauXKKui)):

```
$money = array(
    '$50.45',
    'USD 50.45',
    '50,45',
    'USD$ 50.45'
);

foreach ($money as $val) {
    echo filter_var(
        str_replace(',', '.', $val),
        FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
        FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION
    ), PHP_EOL;
}

// gives 
// 50.45
// 50.45
// 50.45
// 50.45
```

This **will fail** when the string contains fractions and thousand separators. There is a filter flag `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND` that could potentially handle thousand separators as well. But since the thousand separators can indicate fraction in other locales and you want to take it into account, it wont work in your scenario.

For a more powerful parsing alternative try

- [numfmt_parse_currency - Parse a string into a double and a currency using the NumberFormatter.](http://de.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php)

A simple example can be found in [PHP: unformat money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money). The example code in the accepted answer will only parse $50.45 though. The NumberFormatter can be configured with additional rules, so while I am not 100% certain, I think it should be possible with it.

Comment: thousand separator support is really needed in any web-based solution, I voted you down sorry.

Comment: @malhal Yes, I explicitly state that the code snippet won't work with a thousand separator. And I offer two possible workarounds. Have you tried those?