# Decimal money format

Tags: php, numbers, format, money-format

how to convert all numbers to xx,xx decimal format without exploding number or string?
like;

```
8,9 --> 8,90

8,99 --> 8,99

12,1 --> 12,10

129,9 --> 129,90
```

any idea?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: @Rikesh won't work for values with commas though

Comment: http://php.net/sprintf ...

Comment: @Pekka웃 A value with a comma is not a number, but a string. OK, you a right in so far as it seems, that the op is really talks about strings that looks like numbers ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch commas are valid decimal separators in many places outside the anglo-american world. I guess that's his problem. (Edit: ah, looking at your location, you know that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) like:

```
$n = 2.1;
echo number_format($n, 2, ','); // 2,10
```

If you have commas as decimal separators in your input you can convert values to float with:

```
$number = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $string_number)));
```

`str_replace('.', '', $string_number)` is used to remove thousand separators.
`str_replace(',', '.', ... )` is used to replace commas with dots.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `intl` extension enabled, the best approach to the issue (IMO) is given in the accepted answer to this question: [PHP: unformat money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money)

> You can use
>
> - [`NumberFormatter::parseCurrency` - Parse a currency number](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php)
>
> Example from Manual:
>
> ```
> $formatter = new NumberFormatter('de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
> var_dump($formatter->parseCurrency("75,25 €", $curr));
> ```
>
> gives: `float(75.25)`
>
> Note that the [intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) is not enabled by default. Please
>   refer to the [Installation Instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

After that, you'll have a float value and formatting that is a trivial issue using `number_format()`.

If you do not have that extension, check out the regex approach in this question: [What a quick way to clean up a monetary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662105/what-a-quick-way-to-clean-up-a-monetary-string/6662356#6662356)

Answer (score 1):

`$money = number_format($number, 2, ",", ","); // $number must be a float, i.e 8.8`

If your inputs have to have commas as decimal separators, do this too:

```
$money = "20,2";
$fixed_money = floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $money));
echo number_format($fixed_money, 2, ",", ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

str_pad will add the missing zero

```
$val = '1008,95';
$len = strpos($val, ',') + 3;
$newval = str_pad($val, $len, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
echo "Value: " . $newval . "<br>";
```

You have to be sure that your values don't have more than two decimal digits, though

Answer (score 0):

I made a composer package that can deal with such things depending on which currency you are displaying.

https://packagist.org/packages/votemike/money

If you also enter the country it will format the currency in the local way (with or without commas and with the correct number of decimal places)

```
$money = new Money(99.50, 'JPY');
$money->format(); //¥100
```

And so if you just create a new money object with the amount you want to display and the currency you are displaying it in, calling ->format() on that object should give you the result you're looking for.