# Parse formatted Money String into Number

Tags: php

Is there a built in function to parse an integer out of a string containing other non-numeric characters. I'm looking for JavaScript's `parseInt` (ish) functionality in PHP. I want to parse monetary amounts such as `$100`, `£1000.00` or `$10,000` into integers (`100`, `1000` and `10000` respectively). Is there a built in PHP function, or do I have to roll my own?

If I *do* have to write my own, is there another built in function to replace all non-numeric characters, or should I just do a regex replace?

Comment: try with the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money/5140046#5140046. If that doesnt work google/search for a Regular Expression to do that.