# How to format an int in format U.S. in European format

Tags: php, format, int

I get an int in U.S format.

```
$UsInt = "67,450";
```

I need to convert it in European format.

```
$EuInt = "67450";
```

I can not use `str_replace()` to replace the virgule. Do not use `str_replace()` is a mandatory deposit.

i can't use `number_format()`, because i can't pass a comma separated number to this function

Would exist a PHP function to do this? Or someone has already had the problem and was able to get out?

Comment: If `str_replace` is banned, how about `preg_replace`?

Comment: This could help, it is about money but it's the same... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407946/parse-formatted-money-string-into-number

Comment: the client to put these requirements do not use functions such as str_replace () or preg_replace (). because int recovered is written manually, if you use 'str_replace' and if the user made a mistake there will be a problem. if you just format U.S. to EU there is not the risk of error.

Comment: well, you want to put some error checking into your code anyway. there is no magic fool-proof solution.

Comment: I can't do that, because the int I take is already write and i can't say at the user "it's wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: @Gordon♦s solution should be the best.

Not the fastest way, but it should work:

```
$usInt = '67,450';
$explode = explode(',', $usInt);
$euInt = '';

foreach ($explode as $val) {
    $euInt .= $val;
}

echo $euInt;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PHP function `number_format()` :

```
  $EuInt = number_format($UsInt)
```

For more information you can head to the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.number-format.php)

Comment: You can't pass a comma separated number to this function.

Comment: I don't think this works: http://3v4l.org/jSLGK Because according to the document you linked, `number_format` expects the first parameter a float, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

To "unformat" the string, you can use

- [NumberFormatter::parse -- numfmt_parse — Parse a number](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php)

**Example with your formatted strings:**

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
$int = $fmt->parse("67,450");
```

This will give you the raw integer, e.g. 67450 in `$int`.

Then you can either use `number_format` or use

- [NumberFormatter::format -- numfmt_format — Format a number](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php)

**Example from Manual:**

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
echo $fmt->format($int);
```

which would then give 67.450 (with a dot as the thousand separator).

Note that the formatting depends on the locale. And while the region part of a locale might point to Europe, it's not a valid locale on it's own afaik. The British use a comma as the thousand separator (67,450), while the French use a space (67 450) and the Germans use a dot (67.450).

For more information on parsing and formatting numbers, see:

- http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse