# Extract half-width numbers in a character string and separate them into 3 digits with php

Tags: php

How can I extract half-width numbers in a character string and separate them into 3 digits with php?

Example
　original string：I have 10000 dollars.
　After conversion：I have 10,000 dollars.

Comment: Please show us your best attempt (code), you might be closer than you think. What does not work as expected? Please read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am probably missing something with regards to the half-width number, but this seems to work:

```
<?php

$before = 'I have 10000 dollars.';
$expect = 'I have 10,000 dollars.';

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\d+/',
    function($number) { 
        return number_format($number[0]); 
    },
    $before
);

var_dump($result === $expect);
echo $result; // I have 10,000 dollars.
```

Demo https://3v4l.org/oK7bk

If you need control over the number format, check my other answer on this here: [How to format an int in format U.S. in European format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809131/how-to-format-an-int-in-format-u-s-in-european-format/19809414#19809414)