# Making two PHP echo statements do some math

Tags: php, wordpress, math, woocommerce, subtraction

First of all sorry for the most likely simple question. I have two echo statements from woocommerce that I need to subtract from each other.

the first is

```
     <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax(); ?>
```

This gives me the amount of the coupon discount.

The second is

```
     <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?>
```

This gives me the total off all things in the cart.

I need to subtract the coupon discount from the cart subtotal. So I set this up

```
    <?php

    $first_number = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal ;
    $second_number = $woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax ;
    $sum_total = $first_number - $second_number;

    print ($sum_total);

    ?>
```

but obviously the syntax is not right and I just get 0. Please help me with some simple math!

Comment: Are you missing the `()` in your real code as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: unformat money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you've missed `()`

```
$first_number = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
$second_number = $woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax();
```

Without parentheses, you're trying to access a property; but not calling the existent method itself.

Comment: I did miss the parenthesis but even after adding them it still doesn't work. Is there a better way to subtract two echoes?

Comment: I think `echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal() - $woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax();` should work. But at first check values separately.

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix it either.

Comment: As Jimmaay mentioned above problem is in returned value type. Try `echo $woocommerce->cart->subtotal - $woocommerce->cart->discount_cart;`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously one or both of the function returns are non-integers or 0. Find the return of each and change it to the appropriate property or function. Try this public property for the first number.

```
$first_number = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
```

Comment: They all dump out integers here's what I get when I run
`<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?>` $73.40
`<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->subtotal; ?>` 75.61
`<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax(); ?>` $14.68

I'm guessing it has something to do with the $ sign.

Comment: The $ is the problem. Remove it using str_replace or substr

Comment: Like this? 

`<?php

$first_number = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
$second_number = $woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax();
$sum_total = $first_number-$second_number;
$str = str_replace(array('$'), array(''), $str);

print ($sum_total);

?>`

Comment: <?php $first_number = str_replace('$','',$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal()); $second_number = str_replace('$','',$woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax()); $sum_total = $first_number-$second_number;  print ($sum_total); ?>

Comment: That almost did it but it looks like those functions add in some html elements as well so I tried to take out all the characters except for integers but I can't get it to work.

`<?php 
$first_number = preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei',"chr(0x\\1)", $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal()); 
$second_number = preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei',"chr(0x\\1)", $woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax()); 
$sum_total = $first_number-$second_number; 
print ($sum_total); 
?> `

Comment: Try using a different property or function. For the first number use  "$woocommerce->cart->subtotal" which returns an int. Find the another function which returns an int for the other number from the Woocommerce docs. Or be lazy and use strip_tags instead of preg_replace.