# Format number to abbreviated number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, converters, varchar

I have a database with a column containing values in numeric format , for example:

```
5,000 for 5k 

86,600 for 86.6k

4,100,000 for 4.1m
```

while displaying in the browser it should display like 5k for 5000 ,86.6k for 86,600,etc..I need the code in php. If there is any built-in function to do this please mention it .

Comment: So you just want to swap the words?

Comment: The database really contains numbers with commas in it?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in that abbreviates numbers. You'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: No , database contains only numbers not commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have them as numbers, you can use this function directly.

```
function formatValue($size, $precision = 1)
{
    static $suffixes = array('', 'k', 'm');
    $base = log($size) / log(1000);

    return round(pow(1000, $base - floor($base)), $precision) . $suffixes[floor($base)];
}
```

If you don't have them as numbers, use [PHP: unformat money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money)

For you particular case you may use little dirty hack, but I don't recommend it if you have more special cases.

```
function formatValue($size, $precision = 1)
{
    static $suffixes = array('', 'k', 'm');
    $base = log($size) / log(1000);

    if ($base >= 5/3 && $base < 2) {
        return round(pow(1000, $base - floor($base)) / 100, $precision) . 'lakh';
    }

    return round(pow(1000, $base - floor($base)), $precision) . $suffixes[floor($base)];
}
```

Comment: You might wanna add something to remove commas though

Comment: Thank you for the code , but for 100000 its giving 100k ,i need it to be printed as 1 lakh.

Comment: @Rajesh: You can modify the function based on your other formats.

Comment: @Rajesh Updated to reflect your request.