# How to remove all junk characters but keep currency symbols by regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

Here is my code in php

```
<?php
$output = "Clean this copy of invalid non ASCII ¥ äócharacters.";
$output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F\p{Sc})]/','',$output);    
echo($output);
?>
```

Here I want to keep any currency symbols as it is and need to remove junk characters .

What changes should I make in regex for this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define what "junk" is.

Comment: äó  these characters I want to remove

Comment: What about the other hundreds of thousands of possible characters? Define clearly what you want to keep.

Comment: I've added that only all ascii characters should be kept.
Rather than this I need currency symbols to be kept.

Comment: It's better to keep what you want than remove what you don't need. Because always it's some new character that you want to remove. So get the list of wanted characters and replace all the others.

Comment: @gbejic : I want to keep currency symbols and all ascii characters.. Can you please help me to do that ?

Comment: try this ,http://stackoverflow.com/a/5140046/1030951

Comment: @HarshIT : Thanks , But I need to keep all the currencies and all ascii characters too.. So it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `u` modifier to the RegEx and it works nicely:

```
$output = 'Clean this copy of invalid non ASCII ¥$€ äócharacters';
$output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F\p{Sc})]/u','',$output);
```

Outputs

```
Clean this copy of invalid non ASCII ¥$€ characters.
```

Comment: I got this output :
Clean this copy of invalid non ASCII Â¥ characters.
It contains the Â character too..

Comment: You need to be aware that the output will be UTF-8, too. Where do you look at the results? When through a browser you need to tell it that you are outputting UTF-8, for example by adding a `header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");` right at the start of the script.

Comment: @akirk : PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8

Comment: see how it works here: https://eval.in/118611 even without the charset: https://eval.in/118612

Comment: @akirk : so won't it work with PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 ?

Comment: @Priya Perhaps you're just dealing with an encoding problem!?

Comment: @deceze : so how should I proceed further ? please help.

Comment: PriyaBhojani: it does work in that PHP version, too. I suspect, like deceze, that you are jumping between encodings without knowing it. Make sure that you specify  in your editor the encoding to UTF-8, and try to ensure every program in the mix to use UTF-8.

Comment: @deceze Concur; `Â¥` looks like UTF-8 viewed by something which is using Latin-1.  Just make sure you have UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: The parentheses in the character class are superfluous.  Here, they are harmless, but you should understand why they are wrong.

Comment: @akirk : actually this character creates mess with iPhone , the system gets stuck if these characters are received by them. So I need to remove these characters . Tell me if I am going at wrong way ..

Comment: @tripleee : sorry ? I could not get you.. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Ensure that you send the Content-Type header with the encoding so that the device displaying the HTML knows that it is in UTF-8. Just start over and try to stick with UTF-8 everywhere on your path and you should be fine.

Comment: The regex `[(foo)]` is exactly equivalent to the regex `[()fo]`.  That is, everything inside the square brackets is a literal, and there is no order (ranges excepted); duplicates are superfluous, but harmless.  So `[( -~)]` is equivalent to `[() -~]` but since `()` are already included in the range, it's also equivalent to just `[ -~]`.

Answer (score 0):

First question, what do you want to achive? Regex can you make by yourself.

Like:

- Uppercase (Regex = A-Z)
- Lowercase (Regex = a-z)
- Numbers (Regex = 0-9)
- Special chars (Regex = /(slash), \s (space) etc)

To totalize this can be: A-Za-z0-9
However, regex has to many ways to implement, i have no idea about your case or what you want to achive, however, i hope you can do something with this post :)

Comment: I need to keep currency symbols and all ascii characters too.
I am stuck in making this regex using this.
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^(A-Za-z\s\$¥€)]/u','',$output);
```

This will strip out anything other than A-Z, a-z, blank space and symbols $,¥,€

Comment: But I need all the currencies to be allowed.. How would I do that ?

Comment: You have to add that to the pattern