# Adding money strings together and getting a total

Tags: php

I have just coded a basket/cart system for my websitye but I am sturggling on getting the total cost for items in the basket? I have the price for each item (i loop basket items in a loop) what the main question here is how can I add money strings together and get a valid money string total amount like below...

£4.56 +
£2.35 +
£3.00
= £9.91

£2.83 +
£19.83 +
£22
= £44.66 (I think)

Comment: Why not to add the values directly?

Comment: How do you mean? I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Show us the code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I got it working but I only got it working with using the same price for everything then just doing $cost * $items I haven't tried anything for different prices for each product yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: unformat money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/php-unformat-money)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove tha '£' from each item and then convert it to a integer then you create a variable named sum and in a loop you add each element to the sum , there you are the algorithm :

```
 int sum = 0;
   for_each (item i in basket)
    {
        string tmp = i.get_price() ; // get_price returns "£x" string
         sum += to_integer(tmp.sub_str(1,tmp.length()-1)); 
   /* copy from the pos 1 to the end ignoring the '£'*/
    }
```

then the sum variable contains what you want :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a number formatter:

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en-GB",NumberFormatter::CURRENCY); //Make sure you use the correct locale
$total = 0;
foreach ($arrayOfCurrencies as $number) {
   $c = $p = null;
    $total += $f->parseCurrency($number, $c, $p);
}
return $f->formatCurrency($total,$c);
```

Don't use things like `substring` for this when there's built-in ways to do it.