# Convert string to number format in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to convert a string number like `14,767` or `96,812.10` or `6,780,766.50` but if I use
`(double)$fildOfDataBase` or `(float)$fildOfDataBase` this put a integer format as 14 o 96 and I don't know why, so my question is how can i convert a string to a number format, hope some one can help me I'm using laravel 8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unformat money when parsing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/unformat-money-when-parsing-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the thousands separator first

```
(float)str_replace(',', '', $fildOfDataBase);
```

Another more "strict" way to do it is to use `numfmt_parse`

```
//in your case use the en_EN format
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'en_EN', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
numfmt_parse($fmt, $fildOfDataBase);
```